# Scope_identity is giving null values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, scope-identity

I have stored procedure in which I use `scope_identity()`

```sql
Create table table1
    id int,
    name varchar,
    age int
```

```sql
Create procedure details
    @id int,
    @name varchar,
    age int
    
    Select @old_id = id , @name =  name ,@age = age
    from table1 
    where id = @id
    
    if @old_id is null
    begin
        insert into table1(id, name , age)
        Select scope_identity(), @name, @age
    end
```

Error I get:

> cannot insert null into id column, column does not allow null, insert fail

Any idea how to resolve this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (This is a product specific question.)

Comment: I am using SSMS, I am new to this sql

Comment: `SCOPE_IDENTITY` returns the value of last `IDENTITY` value generated in the current scope. What is the statement *prior* to the above `INSERT`? I assume the table you are inserting into prior to that has a column with the `IDENTITY` property?

Comment: its an select statement which take the records of table1 after that this insert statement is there

Comment: The `SELECT` (in your question) is the values you are inserting into `table1`, @jitendersingh ; I'm asking what the statement prior to your `INSERT` is, as that's likely the statement that would be causing `SCOPE_IDENTITY` to have a `NULL` value.

Comment: Is your column `id` in table1 declared as IDENTITY()?

Comment: column id is declared as int

Comment: Can you include the full SP from the top

Comment: @larnu prior to insert there is an if statement

Comment: There's no prior `INSERT` in the scope prior to the `INSERT` into the table `table1`, so yes, `SCOPE_IDENTITY` *will* have the value `NULL`. What are you trying to achieve with `SCOPE_IDENTITY` here?

Comment: Is `table1` the table you want to have the auto-incrementing `id` value?

Comment: I want to add unique id by using scope_identity which is linked to previous id's

Comment: Why not use an `IDENTITY` and have SQL Server handle the value, rather than you pass one to the data engine?

Comment: yes @stu I want autoincrementing

Comment: What do you mean by previous - there is not previous insert in your code above?

Comment: but I have to use scope_identity(its in requirement)

Comment: Please share the "requirement"!

Comment: *"its in requirement"* What *requirement?

Comment: @stu there is previous data in table

Comment: @larnu its an business thing, and they want scope_identity to be used

Comment: So in your example above, you have already inserted into a table which you haven't shown us and you want to use the identity value from that?

Comment: Share with us tghe requirement you have *actually* been given. `SCOPE_IDENTITY` will always return `NULL` if you haven't previously performed an `INSERT`.

Comment: yes should I add screenshot of that table?

Comment: No add the `create table` script

Comment: *"should I add screenshot of that table? "* no, that's no good to us. Give us the whole code and the requirement you have...

Comment: I cant share code due to security reasons, I am sorry for that

Comment: If you won't share the requirement you have been given, nor the a reasonable representation of the code you have then we can't help you, @jitendersingh , but there is no security concerns in sharing psuedo code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer the *why* you're getting a `NULL` here, though it is unlikely that this answer will answer the qusetion you are *really* asking; of course I can't answer that question and you've never told us what that question is.

As explained in all the comments, `SCOPE_IDENTITY` returns the value of the last `IDENTITY` value generated within the **current** scope. To quote the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> Returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in the same scope. A scope is a module: a stored procedure, trigger, function, or batch. Therefore, if two statements are in the same stored procedure, function, or batch, they are in the same scope.

In your procedure there is no prior `INSERT`, so there is not prior generated value, thus `SCOPE_IDENTITY` can **only** have the value `NULL`. This, as a result, means that the `INSERT` statement fails as your column `id` (which I assume is actually a foreign key) cannot be `NULL`.

A *normal* statement with the use of `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` would look something like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (SomeColumn) --SomeTable has a column with the IDENTITY property
VALUES(@SomeValue);

INSERT INTO dbo.AnotherTable(ForeignKey, AnotherColumn)
VALUES(SCOPE_IDENTITY(), @AnotherValue);
```

*Note, as well, that you define your column/parameter `name` as a `varchar(1)`. I would suggest fixing that as there are very few people, if any, who have a single character for their name.*

Comment: there's another possibity - if an insert into `SomeTable` is done, but then other inserts are done into a non-identity table before the use of `scope_identity`, it will also be `null` - it should be saved into local variable immediately following the insert.

Comment: Though true, @Stu , I was simply demonstrating a `INSERT` preceded immediately by another `INSERT`. As we never got the *real* question from the OP,  I felt it someone pointless to go completely in depth about the ins and outs of the function; they have a link to the documentation in the answer if they really want to read up on it's full behaviour.